# Three colors -- Drawing marbles until one color is exhausted

Tags: probability

A bag contains three colors of marbles in known quantities. Marbles are drawn randomly one at a time until any color is exhausted. **What is the probability a given color exhausts first?**

For only two colors, the answer is intuitive -- if a color occupies 1/n*th* of the bag, that is how often it will "survive". Simulating three colors,  I'm not seeing the general pattern.

(The sim is sanity checked with {1,2,3}. Of the 60 combos of **rggbbb**, red exhausts first in 35 of them)

---

> import random
>
> red_out, green_out, blue_out = 0,0,0
>
> runs = 100000
>
> for i in range(0,runs):
>
> ```
> red = 1
> green = 2
> blue = 3
>
> while (red > 0 and green > 0 and blue > 0):
>     rand = random.random()
>     total = red + green + blue
>     frac_red = red/total
>     frac_green = green/total
>     
>     if (rand <= frac_red): red-=1
>     elif (frac_red < rand <= frac_red + frac_green): green-=1
>     else: blue-=1
>    
>     if (red == 0): red_out+=1
>     elif (green == 0): green_out+=1
>     elif (blue == 0): blue_out+=1
> ```
>
> print("RED:",red_out/runs); print("GREEN:",green_out/runs);
> print("BLUE:",blue_out/runs)

Comment: I was engaged in watching the Italian Open, so the brief answer,   I have expanded it for greater conceptual clarity. Cheers ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Looking at it backwards in terms of survival makes perfect sense, since it can then be treated like the two-color problem. Having the simulation available just gave me tunnel vision.

Comment: Glad to have been of help ! $\;\;$ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume we draw from the bag until the bag is empty. What's the probability that blue is last to be exhausted? We denote this event as $B_3$, ie. blue is the third color to be exhausted from the bag. Applying the same logic as the two color case, we get:
$$P(B_{3}) = \frac{b}{r+g+b}$$

Let's assume we already know we are in a situation where blue is the longest survivor. What then would be the probability that green is the second to be exhausted? The second longest-survivor is either green or red, so for all intents and purposes, we can ignore blue.  We get the conditional probability:

$$P(G_{2}|B_{3}) = \frac{g}{r+g}$$

From these we can get probability that "green is second to be exhausted and blue is third":

$$P(G_{2} \land B_{3}) =P(B_{3}) P(G_{2}|B_{3}) = \\
= \left(\frac{b}{r+g+b} \right) \left(\frac{g}{r+g} \right)$$

We may compute:

$$P(R_{1}) = P(G_{2} \land B_{3}) + P(B_{2} \land G_{3}) = \\ = \left(\frac{b}{r+g+b} \right)  \left(\frac{g}{r+g} \right) +  \left(\frac{g}{r+g+b}\right)  \left(\frac{b}{r+b} \right)  $$

Applying to  $r = 1$, $g = 2$, $b = 3$, we get:
$$ P(R_1) = \frac{2}{1+2+3}\;\frac{3}{1+3} + \frac{3}{1+2+3}\;\frac{2}{1+2} = \frac{7}{12} $$

Answer (score 3):

- To get the desired result, the three colors must survive longest either in the order $BGR$ or $GBR$.
- We already know how to compute survival probability for two colors, eg with $2B,4$ "others" in the given example,
  P($B$ survives max)  = P($B$ drawn last) =P($B$ *put* first)$=\frac26$
- The punchline is that having computed the survival probability of blue, to compute the survival probability of the next color, *we just imagine that blue marbles have vanished from the   row*, so again we have only two colors to deal with ! And we can iterate this process, always dealing with only two colors at a time, for any number of colors.

Thus P($B$ survives longest followed by $G$) $=\frac36\frac23 =\frac13$

and ($G$ survives longest followed by $B$) $= \frac26\frac34 = \frac14$

Finally, P(red is first to "die") $= \frac13+\frac14 = \frac7{12} \equiv \frac{35}{60}$ of your simulation

Comment: I wonder why I couldn't see user3257842 answer while I was posting mine. Anyway, that answer is explained in more detail than mine, so I am upvoting it.